# Transform GA API output to structured json format

Tags: json, jolt

### I would like to convert json data below into structured json format using Jolt Transformation.

**Input data:**

```
  "containsSampledData": false,
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "ga:pagePath",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventCategory",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventAction",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:totalEvents",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:uniqueEvents",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:avgEventValue",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "FLOAT"
    }
  ],
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:totalEvents": "174594",
    "ga:uniqueEvents": "107567",
    "ga:avgEventValue": "57472.307753989255"
  },
  "rows": [
    [
      "/",
      "BannerPromotion",
      "(not set)",
      "9",
      "6",
      "0.0"
    ],
    [
      "/",
      "BannerPromotion",
      "Sample Test",
      "30",
      "25",
      "0.0"
    ],
    [
      "/",
      "BannerPromotion",
      "Sample Test",
      "3",
      "3",
      "0.0"
    ]
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  "pagePath" : "/",
  "eventCategory" : "BannerPromotion",
  "eventAction" : "(not set)",
  "totalEvents" : "9",
  "uniqueEvents" : "6",
  "avgEventValue" : "0.0"
},

{
  "pagePath" : "/",
  "eventCategory" : "BannerPromotion",
  "eventAction" : "Sample Test",
  "totalEvents" : "3",
  "uniqueEvents" : "3",
  "avgEventValue" : "0.0"
}
```

Scenario is I'm pulling data from Google Analytics API and it gave me the input data format above which is not the right format before storing the data into database table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Jolt transformation library is used to convert a JSON value to another form of a JSON value. But, the input here is not a valid JSON value.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan do you know a way you can parse this input into desired format?

Comment: Please show us code you've already tried, or where your research into possible solutions has led you so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this as your input

Input:

```
{
  "containsSampledData": false,
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "ga:pagePath",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventCategory",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventAction",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:totalEvents",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:uniqueEvents",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:avgEventValue",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "FLOAT"
    }
  ],
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:totalEvents": "174594",
    "ga:uniqueEvents": "107567",
    "ga:avgEventValue": "57472.307753989255"
  },
  "rows": [
    [
      "/",
      "BannerPromotion",
      "(not set)",
      "9",
      "6",
      "0.0"
    ],
    [
      "/",
      "BannerPromotion",
      "Sample Test",
      "30",
      "25",
      "0.0"
    ],
    [
      "/",
      "BannerPromotion",
      "Sample Test",
      "3",
      "3",
      "0.0"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can work with this Jolt to create an output in the format you required

Jolt Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rows": {
        "*": {
          "0": "[&1].pagePath",
          "1": "[&1].eventCategory",
          "2": "[&1].eventAction",
          "3": "[&1].totalEvents",
          "4": "[&1].uniqueEvents",
          "5": "[&1].avgEventValue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for exerting effort for the solution. Your the best!